# Uninitialized String offset when looping over array

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to code a Pick'em application where users select which team will win each game of a ROUND in a tournament. I.E a tournament has many rounds, I calculate winners per round and keep record of  wins.

**I am currently working on getting the winners at the end of a round**

My logic to tackle the above problem is as follows:

- GET EVENT INFO
- GET MEMBER SELECTIONS
- GET Winning Teams
- ***GET MEMBERS WHO SELECTED CORRECT TEAM (My problem is here!)***
- Count Which Member Selected the most correct teams for round

I have a DB structure PART of it looks like this

[image]

I am posting my code below, I'm hoping someone can point me out as to where I am going wrong.

I can confirm the following

- Step 1 Tested - Working
- Step 2 Tested - Working
- Step 3 Tested - Working
- Step - 4 MY PROBLEM ERROR (`Uninitialized string offset`)
- Step - 5 Fix Step 4 first

//### STEP 1 ###

```
//GET EVNT INFO
$sql="Select * FROM events WHERE tournament = 'IPL'  AND round ='5'";
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        foreach($result as $results){
            $eventNr[] = $results['event_id'];
            $t1[] = $results['team1'];
            $t2[] = $results['team2'];
            $t1Score[] = $results['team1Score']; //Event finished score uploaded
            $t2Score[] = $results['team2Score']; //Event finished score uploaded                
        }//foreach

//### STEP 2 ###
//GET MEMBER SELECTIONS

$sql="Select * FROM multiple_picks WHERE tournament = 'IPL'  AND round ='5' ORDER BY round_game_nr";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        foreach($result as $results){
            $memberNr[] = $results['member_nr'];
            $pickId[] = $results['pick_id'];
             $eventId[] = $results['event_id'];
             $pick[] = $results['pick'];
            $score[] = $results['score'];
            $tournament[] = $results['tournament'];
            $round[] = $results['round'];
            $rgm[] = $results['round_game_nr'];
        }//for each

####STEP 3 ######       
//GET Winning Teams
        $winner = array();

        foreach($eventNr as $id => $winners){
            if($t1Score[$id] > $t2Score[$id]){
                 $winner = $t1[$id];    
            }//if
                else if($t2Score[$id] > $t1Score[$id]){
                     $winner = $t2[$id];    
                }//else if
        }//foreach

#### STEP 4 GET MEMBERS WHO SELECTED CORRECT TEAM ####
        //GET WINNING MEMBERS
        $correct = array();
        foreach($pickId as $id => $picked){
            if($pick[$id] == $winner[$id])
            {
                echo $correct = $memberNr[$id];
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Been stuck on this for hours any help **OR ADVICE** greatly appreciated

Comment: Show the full error message please **and an indication which line it refers to.**

Comment: what does this line currently output? `echo $correct = $memberNr[$id];`

Comment: @deceze error message is `uninitialized string offset` at the `if statement` on the last `foreach`

Comment: That means either `$pick` or `$winner` or both are *strings*, not arrays. Debug backwards to figure out why.

Comment: @deceze I did check both `$pick` and `$winner` both are printing their values correctly it is only when I compare one with the other in the `if statment` when I get the problem...

Comment: You are assigning something to `$winner =` in the previous loop, not pushing something into its array; again: **it does not look like `$winner` is an array**, so `$winner[$id]` is producing an error.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your ongoing help I realize it is difficult trying to decipher the code, `$winner` takes the team who won the match in STEP 3 it then gets compared to the Members pick with `$pick` THUS `if($pick == $winner)` `$winner` has the winning team and it gets compared against the members selection `$pick` to see if he selected the correct team

Comment: Just go ahead and put a `var_dump($winner)` on the line right before the error is produced. Does that output `Array`? Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first query return only one event, you can find who picks the correct team like that :

```
//GET EVNT INFO
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE tournament = 'IPL' AND round = '5'";
$query = $db->query($sql);

// Store the event info inside an array.
$event = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//### STEP 2 ###
//GET MEMBER SELECTIONS
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM multiple_picks WHERE tournament = 'IPL'  AND round ='5' ORDER BY round_game_nr";
$query = $db->query($sql);

// Store members inside a collection of member.
$picks = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//### STEP 3 ###
//GET Winning Teams
$winner = null;
if ($event['team1Score'] > $event['team2Score']) {
    $winner = $event['team1'];
} elseif ($event['team1Score'] < $event['team2Score']) {
    $winner = $event['team2'];
}

// ### STEP 4 GET MEMBERS WHO SELECTED CORRECT TEAM ###
//GET WINNING MEMBERS
$correct = [];
foreach ($picks as $pick) {
    if ($pick['pick'] === $winner) {
        $correct[] = $pick['member_nr'];
        echo 'Member ' . $pick['member_nr'] . ' picks correctly !';
    }
}
```